# Workflow Status URL in EMail

Tags: 2010, designer-workflow

I have a list A with a workflow which starts a new task for an user. In the associated task list is a seperate workflow which sends an email to the relevant user.(We stopped sending the automatic email from sharepoint task lists) Is it possible to send the status workflow url from the workflow in list A in the workflow-email from the task list?

Answer (score 0):

I believe there is no straight forward way to do this.. 
As a workaround you can do this, have a dummy column in listA and once an item is created have the W/F associated with listA to update the column with the status url and use it in the W/F associated with task list.